# Basis of a Subspace given an Equation.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hi, I was wondering if this question is asking us to find the basis of the kernel of this transformation from $\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the subspace is the set of orthogonal vectors to $(2,-1,2,4)$ and so one should find a basis for the orthogonal complement of the subspace spanned by that vector.

Added: and yes, this orthogonal complement is the kernel of the linear map $T\colon\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$T(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=2x_1-x_2+2x_3+4x_4.$$
Since the range of $T$ has dimension $1$, the kernel will have dimension $4-1=3$.

Comment: I see, but why does the dimension have to be 3 for the subspace? Also isnt the dimension of the kernel of the transformation from R4 -> R, 3?

Comment: I added details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. Since the range of the linear map is $\mathbb{R}$, because, for instance, the vector $(1,0,0,0)$ maps to $2\ne0$, the rank-nullity theorem tells you that the kernel has dimension $4-1=3$.

You find a basis by solving with respect to one of the unknowns and give the other values that ensure linear independence. So, since we can do
$$
x_2=2x_1+2x_3+4x_4
$$
a basis consists of the vectors
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad
\begin{bmatrix}0\\4\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$